# VB.Net | Retrieving Web URLs from page source using Substring

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently having difficulties writing a program that retrieves website URLs from the web source that is being processed (eg. finding all URLs beginning with 'http://www.bbc.co.uk' within that particular webpage).

My current code for this area is:

```
 Dim sourceString As String                                    'web page source
 Dim searchSite As String = webAddressesSource(s)              'site to search

      ''trawls each character of websource with the length of the website + 10
        For n = 0 To sourceString.Length - searchSite.Length - 10

            If sourceString.Substring(n, searchSite.Length) = searchSite Then
                lstOutput.Items.Add(sourceString.Substring(n, searchSite.Length + (10)))
            End If

        Next n
```

So this code would output all website links that equal to the site being searched, as well as 10 characters after the end of 'searchSite' eg. 'http://www.bbc.co.uk##########'

This outputs strings such as:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/">TV</
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/">R
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/">Fo
```

However, I require to get web links output like the following:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/    
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/
```

Any help or ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: Or use a Regular Expression.